# WordPress shortcode parameters

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to get all parameters in the WordPress shortcode?

For example,

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts(
             array(
                 'foo' => 'something',
                 'bar' => 'something else',
             ),
             $atts);

    return "foo = {$a['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode('bartag', 'bartag_func');
```

Here `[bartag]` is shortcode.

Is there a way to know the values of `shortcode_atts` or value of `foo` `bar`, etc.?

Is there a way to get all variable values inside the `bartag_func`?

Comment: check var_dump($atts) inside bartag_func

Answer (score 5):

You can use [this function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) to get all values from shortcode:

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'foo' => 'no foo',
            'bar' => 'default bar',
        ), $atts, 'bartag');

    return 'bartag: ' . $atts['foo'] . ' ' . $atts['bar'];
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

> [bartag foo="koala" bar="bears"] outputs the following: bartag: koala
>   bears
>
> [bartag foo="koala"] outputs the following: bartag: koala default bar